# How do I create a Progress bar using the value of an ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, progress-bar

Before the code below, a user enters the title of a book they read. There is then a total count automatically populated in **id="bookcount"**.

I have a progressbar for the book count, but how can I make it automatically grab the number in **bookcount**...so the progress bar can update as more books are entered. (Basically, **value="2"** needs to somehow pull the number instead of manually assigning the value.)

```
<div id="bookcount">2</div>
<label for="bookprogress">progress:</label>
<progress id="bookprogress" max="5" value="2"> 70% </progress>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#bookprogress").val("#bookcount");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the number with `var bookCount = +$('#bookcount').text()` and then set it using `$('#bookprogress').attr('value',bookCount);`.

First line of code takes content of a `div` and casts it to the number using simple `+` in front of it. The other line just sets the value of the progress bar to the `div` value.

```js
var bookCount = +$('#bookcount').text()
$('#bookprogress').attr('value',bookCount);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="bookcount">2</div>
<label for="bookprogress">progress:</label>
<progress id="bookprogress" max="5" value="0"> 70% </progress>
```